# Setup intellij on spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, intellij-14

The error below is thrown when I try to start a spring boot project on my m1 Macbook Pro. How can I fix this, and what is the reason for this?
**Error:**

```
   Abnormal build process termination:
nice -n 10 /users/riccardo/library/java/javavirtualmachines/azul-16.0.2-1/contents/home/bin/java -xmx700m -djava. Awt. Headless=true --add-opens jdk. Compiler/com. Sun. Tools. Javac. Api=all-unnamed --add-opens jdk. Compiler/com. Sun. Tools. Javac. Util=all-unnamed --add-opens jdk. Compiler/com. Sun. Tools. Javac. Code=all-unnamed --add-opens jdk. Compiler/com. Sun. Tools. Javac. Comp=all-unnamed --add-opens jdk. Compiler/com. Sun. Tools. Javac. File=all-unnamed --add-opens jdk. Compiler/com. Sun. Tools. Javac. Main=all-unnamed --add-opens jdk. Compiler/com. Sun. Tools. Javac. Model=all-unnamed --add-opens jdk. Compiler/com. Sun. Tools. Javac. Parser=all-unnamed --add-opens jdk. Compiler/com. Sun. Tools. Javac. Processing=all-unnamed --add-opens jdk. Compiler/com. Sun. Tools. Javac. Tree=all-unnamed --add-opens jdk. Compiler/com. Sun. Tools. Javac. Jvm=all-unnamed -dpreload. Project. Path=/users/riccardo/desktop/progetti/personali/quotereportserver "-dpreload. Config. Path=/users/riccardo/library/application support/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/options" -dcompile. Parallel=false -drebuild. On. Dependency. Change=true -didea. Inttointbtree. Page. Size=32768 -djdt. Compiler. Usesinglethread=true -daether. Connector. Resumedownloads=false -dio. Netty. Initialseeduniquifier=3479120019962095349 -dfile. Encoding=utf-8 -duser. Language=en -duser. Country=it -didea. Paths. Selector=ideaic2022.2 "-didea. Home. Path=/applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents" "-didea. Config. Path=/users/riccardo/library/application support/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2" "-didea. Plugins. Path=/users/riccardo/library/application support/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/plugins" -djps. Log. Dir=/users/riccardo/library/logs/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/build-log "-djps. Fallback. Jdk. Home=/applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/jbr/contents/home" -djps. Fallback. Jdk. Version=17.0.4.1 -dio. Netty. Nounsafe=true -djava. Io. Tmpdir=/users/riccardo/library/caches/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/compile-server/quotereportserver_35242acb/_temp_ -djps. Backward. Ref. Index. Builder=true -dkotlin. Incremental. Compilation=true -dkotlin. Incremental. Compilation. Js=true -dkotlin. Daemon. Enabled -dkotlin. Daemon. Client. Alive. Path=\"/var/folders/rt/m71wvw7s6yj5_d479mj15bym0000gp/t/kotlin-idea-16691048973323777495-is-running\" "-djps. Kotlin. Home=/users/riccardo/library/application support/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/plugins/kotlin/kotlinc" -dtmh. Instrument. Annotations=true -dtmh. Generate. Line. Numbers=true -dcompile. Parallel. Max. Threads=4 -dcompile. Parallel=true --add-opens java. Base/java. Util=all-unnamed -dscala. Compile. Server. System. Dir=/users/riccardo/library/caches/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/scala-compile-server -dscala. Compile. Server. Socket. Connect. Timeout. Milliseconds=10000 -dscala. Compiler. Indices. Rebuild=true -dide. Propagate. Context=false -classpath "/applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher. Jar" org. Jetbrains. Jps. Cmdline. Launcher "/applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/lib/util. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/lib/util_rt. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/lib/annotations. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/lib/3rd-party-rt. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/lib/jna. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/lib/lz4-java. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/lib/protobuf. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/lib/jps-model. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/java/lib/javac2. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/lib/forms_rt. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/lib/idea_rt. Jar: /users/riccardo/library/application support/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/plugins/kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/lib/util. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/javafx/lib/javafx-jps. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/javafx/lib/javafx-common. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/space/lib/space-java-jps. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/uidesigner/lib/jps/java-guiforms-jps. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/intellilang/lib/java-langinjection-
jps. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/groovy/lib/groovy-jps. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps. Jar: /applications/intellij idea ce. App/contents/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps. Jar: /users/riccardo/library/application support/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/plugins/scala/lib/scala-library. Jar: /users/riccardo/library/application

support/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/plugins/scala/lib/compiler-shared. Jar: /users/riccardo/library/application support/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/plugins/scala/lib/jps/nailgun. Jar: /users/riccardo/library/application support/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/plugins/scala/lib/jps/compiler-jps. Jar: /users/riccardo/library/application support/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/plugins/scala/lib/jps/sbt-interface. Jar: /users/riccardo/library/application support/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/plugins/scala/lib/jps/incremental-compiler. Jar: /users/riccardo/library/application support/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/plugins/scala/lib/jps/scala-parallel-collections. Jar: /users/riccardo/library/application support/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/plugins/scala/lib/spray-json_2.13-1.3.5. Jar: /users/riccardo/library/application support/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/plugins/scala/lib/scala-compiler-indices-protocol_2.12-0.1.1. Jar" org. Jetbrains. Jps. Cmdline. Buildmain 127.0.0.1 61152 4782dc89-f679-499a-950d-566b6c03131e /users/riccardo/library/caches/jetbrains/ideaic2022.2/compile-server
nice: /users/riccardo/library/java/javavirtualmachines/azul-16.0.2-1/contents/home/bin/java: no such file or directory
```

Comment: `/users/riccardo/library/java/javavirtualmachines/azul-16.0.2-1/contents/home/bin/java: no such file or directory`

Add information regarding the IntelliJ version, whether it's a community edition or an ultimate edition, the result of `java -version` on the terminal window etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check for language version. Go to `File > Project Structure` select `Project` under the `Project Settings` check the language version. Then you can do  `Invalidate Cache and Restart`